# Javascript - increment and double a value

Tags: javascript, html, double, increment

I want to write my first code. I made this, but it still needs a change.
There is shown a value and this value can be changed with 2 buttons. When the buttons Increment is pushed, the value has to go with one higher. If the button Double is pressed, then the value has to be double (e.g. going from 3 to 6). Now it is coded like a decrement, but this needs to be changed.

```js
var x = 0
var element = document.getElementById("value");
element.innerHTML = x;

function button1() {
  element.innerHTML = ++x;
}

function button2() {
  element.innerHTML = --x;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <title> First code </title>

  <body>
    <div id="value"></div>
    <input type=button value="Increment" onclick="button1()" />
    <input type=button value="Double" onclick="button2()" />

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Convert the `innerHTML` to an integer and multiply by 2 then set the `innerHTML` to the new value. HINT: you can use `parseInt`

Comment: so multiplication instead of addition.

Comment: Why are you subtracting in the function that's supposed to double?

Answer (score 2):

You need to multiply by 2 rather than subtract 1.

There's no need for the `x` variable, you can operate directly on the `innerHTML`. JavaScript's type juggling will automatically convert it to a number when you use these arithmetic operators on it.

```js
var element = document.getElementById("value");
element.innerHTML = '0';

function button1() {
  element.innerHTML++;
}

function button2() {
  element.innerHTML *= 2;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <title> First code </title>

  <body>
    <div id="value"></div>
    <input type=button value="Increment" onclick="button1()" />
    <input type=button value="Double" onclick="button2()" />

  </body>

</html>
```